# Which sentence is correct: 我每个星期去四次大学 or 我每个星期去大学四次?

Tags: grammar, usage, difference, word-order

Wondering where to put a time frequency word in a Chinese sentence?

Which one of the following sentences is correct?

我每个星期去四次大学 or 我每个星期去大学四次?

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct.

You can say 我每个星期去四次大学 or 我每个星期去大学四次.

Answer (score 2):

the former sounds weird. it roughly translates to "I go four times to university every week". while the latter feels more natural, "I go to university four times a week".

Comment: Agree. The latter one is more natural, though the former one is also acceptable in spoken language.

Answer (score 2):

All are right but means a little different.

If you want to stress going to college, you may use the 1st one.
If you want to stress 4 times, you should use the 2nd one.

Answer (score 2):

Both of the sentences are correct and they have the same meaning.

Notice:

In "我每个星期去四次大学", "university" sounds less important to you, just like "我每天去六次厕所 (I go to toilet six times a day)".

"我每个星期去大学四次" emphasises on the number of times you go to university. "University" sounds more important in this case.

Answer (score 0):

我 每个星期 去 四次 大学

or

我 每个星期 去 大学 四次

Both sentences are OK in modern Chinese.
I myself prefer the latter.

In fact, the word order in Chinese is not that strict.
So,  the above example sentence can also be as follows:

每个星期 我 去 大学 四次

每个星期 我 去 四次 大学

大学 每个星期 我 去 四次

我 去 大学 每个星期 四次

我 去 大学 四次 每个星期

每个星期 四次 我 去 大学

Perhaps there are more possible combinations.

Comment: 呃。。。如果这样说话的话，现实里会被打吧？

Answer (score 0):

In real life selfdom people would say `去大学`, this is very wired. you can say : `我去大学上班` or `我去上班` or `我去大学的办公室`

so, in these 2 sentences, the content in bracks`[]` are 副词(adv), which order is flex.

- 我[每个星期]去[四次]大学
- 我[每个星期]去大学[四次]

so, both of them are grammar correct

Answer (score 0):

我每个星期去四次大学, you repeat the action（verb) 去 four times a week.

Such as: 你每个星期去几次大学？去四次。

我每个星期去大学四次, you repeat the whole event（verb+noun）去大学 four times a week。

Such as: 你每个星期都很忙吗？是啊。我要去大学四次,去医院看我妈妈五次，还有很多事情。

**Sometimes it is critical to have the correct order of words.** For example:

我每个月领取四次三千五百元的工资。（OK） (14000)

我每个月领取四次工资, 三千五百元。(not good)

我每个月领取四次工资, 每次三千五百元。(OK) (14000)

我每个月领取四次工资, 一共三千五百元。(OK) (3500)

我每个月领取三千五百元工资四次。(not good)

我每个月领取三千五百元工资，要分成四次领取。(OK) (3500)

我的工资是每个月三千五百元, 分成四次领取。(OK) (3500)

我每次领三千五百元工资, 每个月领四次。(OK) (14000)

Answer (score -1):

我一周去四次大学还是我每个去大学四次？

我的回复: 一周 与每周 都是 正确的用法与语法，但是每周用的更多一点。 你应该把：  每周 写成了：  每个， 每个 用在这里是不正确的。

Comment: Welcome to [chinese.se]! It might be worthwhile [edit]ing your answer to include an English version, since the author asked it in English as well.